# wp_enqueue_script in the footer

Tags: wordpress, hook, action, footer

Having problems enqueuing a script in the footer.

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js', array(), false, true);
```

Here's the wp_enqueue_script definition:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
     $handle
    ,$src
    ,$deps
    ,$ver
    ,$in_footer 
);
```

As you can see I am setting $in_footer to true. This does not work for me. Without that argument it works fine and puts it in header.php. Why doesn't it work with $in_footer?

Answer (score 25):

By default WordPress default JavaScripts won’t move to the footer, a workaround is to add its path :

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery','/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js','','',true);
```

[See detailled post about this](http://blog.cloudfour.com/getting-all-javascript-into-the-footer-in-wordpress-not-so-fast-buster/)

Comment: using both: true, $in_footer = true works for me but I'm not sure why. When I remove the first true, it doesn't work, but using both together does.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have the `wp_footer()` right before the `</body>` tag.  See the [$in_footer parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Parameters) for more info.  You also need to call this before wp_head has run. Try also using this action.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts_to_pages');
```

Another thing to try is using `NULL` as 3rd and 4th parameters.

Comment: `Make sure you have the wp_footer() right before the </body> tag`. Just started WordPress this 2023 and this answer from 2012 fixed my problem. Thank you Nick!

Answer (score 2):

To follow on from Nick's reply just wanted to add an example. Add all 5 parameters for the wp_enqueue_script function then the script is loaded in the footer. Adding NULL instead of leaving the parameters blank works here for $deps and $ver.

Reference Format:

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

General Example:

```
wp_enqueue_script('custom-handle-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom-src.js', NULL, NULL, true );
```

Your Example:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js', NULL, NULL, true);
```

Source:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @Nick's answer;

if you have a PHP problem before `wp_footer()` you wont be able to see your script in footer. Source is https://wordpress.org/support/topic/enqueuing-scripts-in-footer-does-not-working-with-wordpress-36.